# How to count the 'number of values of a particular variable of a tibble' in an interval in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

packages required

'dplyr'

'nycflights13'

the tibble I am using is

```
 q4<-flights%>%group_by(year,month,day)%>%summarise(cancelled=sum(is.na(dep_time)),avg_delay=mean(arr_delay,na.rm = T),totalflights=n())

 q4<-q4%>%mutate(prop=cancelled/totalflights)
```

using

```
q4%>%ungroup()%>%count(prop)
```

gives me

```
     # A tibble: 342 x 2
       prop     n
       <dbl> <int>
    1 0           7
    2 0.00101     1
    3 0.00102     2
    4 0.00102     1
    5 0.00102     1
    6 0.00102     1
    7 0.00103     1
    8 0.00103     1
    9 0.00104     1
    10 0.00104     1
    # ... with 332 more rows
```

Is there a way that I can ( without using brute force logic like for loops etc)
get output in the desired form, I am looking for a one-line or two-line solution.
Is there a function in dplyr that does it??

Desired Output:

```
     # A tibble: X x Y
       prop     n
       <dbl> <int>
    1 0-0.1       45          #random numbers
    2 0.1-0.2     54
    3 0.2-0.3     23
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below, I use `cut` to bin the data and then `table` to count instances of each bin.

```
data.frame(cut(q4$prop, breaks = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3)) %>% table)
```

produces

```
#           . Freq
# 1   (0,0.1]  341
# 2 (0.1,0.2]   13
# 3 (0.2,0.3]    2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use after  `q4<-q4%>%mutate(prop=cancelled/totalflights)` :

```
q4 %>% ungroup() %>%
mutate(category = cut(prop, breaks = c(-Inf,0.1,0.2,Inf), labels = c("0-0.1","0.1-0.2", "0.2 - 0.3") %>%
count(category)
```

I believe it will work

Comment: Getting the following error:
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `labels` must be length 365 (the number of rows) or one, not 3

Comment: You can do this without "labels".

Answer (score 0):

I figured one out myself, which I also feel is the best.

```
           q4%>%ungroup()%>%count(cut_width(prop,0.025))
```

Output:

```
                   # A tibble: 11 x 2
                  `cut_width(prop, 0.025)`     n
                    <fct>                    <int>
                 1 [-0.0125,0.0125]           233
                 2 (0.0125,0.0375]             66
                 3 (0.0375,0.0625]             26
                 4 (0.0625,0.0875]             13
                 5 (0.0875,0.112]              14
                 6 (0.112,0.138]                4
```